# Get the column which have maximum sum value from matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Let's say:

```
import numpy as np    
f=np.matrix("1 2; 3 4 ; 5 6")
```

Is retrieving number of column which have maximum sum of column from matrix possible? How?

Answer (score 3):

You could write:

```
>>> f.sum(axis=0).argmax()
1
```

So column `1` sums to the greatest value.

To clarify what this does: `f.sum(axis=0)` sums the columns of the matrix `f`, returning the matrix `matrix([[ 9, 12]])`. Then `argmax()` is used to find the index of the maximum value in this matrix of sums.

Comment: Additionally, can i do that like "get column which sum of its is>0". Without argmax or argmin?

Comment: @SuatAtan: for more general conditions you could use `np.where`. For example: `np.where(f.sum(axis=0) > 0)` returns a tuple telling you at what indices the sums are positive.