# Get the index of which the sum is max Python 3

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix, and I want to find the index which has the maximum row sum:

```
 [[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [2. 4. 4. 5.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Here it should be returned 3.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This returns me the row and not the index max(results, key=sum), being results the matrix

Comment: You can use `numpy` module [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29217161/9511702) example how to do this. Instead of `axis=0` do `axis=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is

```
 np.argmax(my_array.sum(axis=1))
```

The `axis=1` sums each row to a single number, producing a 1D array of sums, and then, `argmax` finds the index of the largest sum

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[0, 4, 3,0],
     [0, 0, 0,0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [2, 4, 4, 5],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]]

length_array=[sum(value) for value in a]
print(length_array.index(max(length_array)))
```

Comment: This is numpy arrays, not python lists

Comment: This uses `O(number of rows)` in memory; you could get `O(1)` by using a simple `for` loop.

Comment: who said it should be numpy array?

Comment: It would be better if your could include some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

OR using `np.where`:

```
print(np.where(arr.sum(axis=1)))
```

Output:

```
(array([3], dtype=int64),)
```

To an integer do:

```
print(np.where(arr.sum(axis=1))[0][0])
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: what are the advantages of using `np.where`? Thanks!